# Gaps appear in the model after normal Blender bake

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I'm just starting in Blender and this is my first sculpture. After doing the retopology and uv unwrapping (it has seams where it shouldn't, yes), I was about to do the bake of normals. Once it's done, these gaps appear. I haven't found the solution. Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Does your mesh happen to have any Quick Effects or Backface Culling applied to it?

Comment: I don´t think so, but, how can I check it if they are applied?

Comment: Judging by the picture of your *Modifier Properties*, you have no Quick effects enabled. However, in the Settings tab in *Material Properties*, there is a little checkbox labeled Backface Culling. If this is enabled, try turning it off to see what happens.